# The content of element type "" must match in xml

Tags: xml, dtd

DTD

```
<!ELEMENT ShopDetails (CEO, ShopName, Address,                              
TelephoneNumber, Website?, Logo, Sales*)>
<!ELEMENT Item (ItemNumber, TypesOfCar, Warranty?,        
Discount?, Description, CarDetails+)>
<!ELEMENT ItemNumber (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT TypesOfCar (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST TypesOfCar category CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT Warranty (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Discount (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Description (#PCDATA)>
```

It is showing this type of error while validating the DTD

```
35: 11  The content of element type "Item" must match
```

Comment: error  35: 11 The content of element type "Item" must match "(ItemNumber,TypesOfCar,Warranty?,Discount?,Description,CarDetails+)".
 65: 18 The content of element type "CarDetails" must match "(BrandName,CarName,Price,Sunproof?,Mileage,SupportUSBCharging?)".
 85: 11 The content of element type "Item" must match "(ItemNumber,TypesOfCar,Warranty?,Discount?,Description,CarDetails+)".
 86: 11 The content of element type "Sales" must match "(item)*".

Comment: If you want an explanation of the error (I guess that's your question, though you haven't said so) then we'll need to see the XML in question.